# Apache Kylin - Cube build errors

Tags: cube, kylin

I am trying to build a simple cube in Apache Kylin. This has two dimensions and a measure. The dimensions have only a single level hierarchy. However when i run the build cube, i keep getting the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.kylin.common.util.DateFormat.isAllDigits(DateFormat.java:121)
at org.apache.kylin.common.util.DateFormat.stringToMillis(DateFormat.java:104)
at org.apache.kylin.common.util.DateFormat.stringToMillis(DateFormat.java:91)
at org.apache.kylin.dict.lookup.LookupStringTable.convertRow(LookupStringTable.java:86)
```

from the step Build Dimension Dictionary.

```
#4 Step Name: Build Dimension Dictionary
```

Not sure what is the issue. There is no null in the table data. Has anybody faced this similar issue. Please help.

Regards

Bala

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Kylin version 1541. I upgraded to 1.6 to sort this issue.